# Printing for value of ArrayList Integer

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, printing, element

I'm working on a small game that essentially has piles of coins, and you must take some coins from a pile then the program prints out the resulting piles in the format:

```
Pile 1: ****
Pile 2: *****
Pile 3: **
```

I have an array list that store all these values like so:

```
List<Integer> coins = new ArrayList<>();
[4,5,2]
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to properly print the *'s.

How can I write this code to print out a * for each value in an element. IE 4 *'s if the element value is 4?

Here is my current method:

```
static void printGameState(){
    for(int i = 0; i <= coins.size()-1; i++){
        int k = i+1;
        System.out.print("Pile " + k + ": ");
        for(int j = 0; j <= coins.indexOf(i); j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using this condition:

`j <= coins.indexOf(i);`

Use this condition:

`j < coins.get(i);`

Try it:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= coins.size()-1; i++) {
    int k = i+1;

    System.out.print("Pile " + k + ": ");
    for(int j = 0; j < coins.get(i); j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

You'll get:

```
Pile 1: ****
Pile 2: *****
Pile 3: **
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. If I wanted to subtract the value of one of the arraylist elements, how would I go about doing this?  `coins.set(index, coins.get(index) - numCoins);` would this be correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have to **look at the values of the different stacks** by accessing the array `coins[i]` instead of using the number of stacks as stack height:

```
static void printGameState(){
    for(int i = 0; i < coins.size(); i++) {
        // Build the coin stack
        String coinStack = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < coins.get(i); j++) {
            coinStack += "*";
        }

        // And output it
        System.out.println("Pile " + (i + 1) + ": " + coinStack);            
    }
}
```

Comment: `coins` is not type `int[]` so `coins[i]` wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should be using < instead of <=. Also, you should be able to use `get(i)` to take the value at index i.

```
static void printGameState(){
    for(int i = 0; i < coins.size(); i++){
        int k = i+1;
        System.out.print("Pile " + k + ": ");
        for(int j = 0; j < coins.get(i); j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}
```

You could also make it a bit cleaner by forming another method to print `*` such as:

```
public void ast(int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

Then the contents of printGameState loop would be

```
int k = i+1;
System.out.print("Pile " + k + ": ");
ast(coins.get(i));
```